# ipad browser position

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

is possible to set the position of browser's window always on top left on the ipad Screen?! Because when i rotate my ipad if width of my website is more than ipad screen the window is position on top right.
thx

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of your window for ipads like that in your HTML code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: the problem is: if i load my page in landscape orientation the page is ok. Also if i load my page on portrait mode is ok, but if i load my page in landscape mode and then i rotate the ipad, the window width is more than screen width..so the window browser is align right..damn!

Comment: just fixed! with jquery i resize all div with widht more than 768px only for ipad!